# I don't understand why my std::string string is not containing the UTF-8 string correctly

Tags: c++, string, encoding, utf-8, wstring

**EDIT:** I am editing my question to provide everyone with clearer information on my issues through code. I've also changed my input string from Japanese to a Greek string so kindly take note. Thank you very much!

---

I have this `wstring` input below:

```
wstring command = L"Σὲ γνωρίζω ἀπὸ τὴν κόψη";
```

This is the existing code (take note: I did not create this code) that converted the `std::wstring` to `std::string`:

```
string wstring2string(const wstring& str) 
{
   string str2(str.length(), L' ');
   std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), str2.begin());
   return str2;
}
```

After this function, the value in the string became like this:

```
£r ³½ÉÁw¶É
```

[image: Debugged string values here]

This function works well with non-UTF-8 and non-Unicode texts. I just can't wrap my head around why it can't work with UTF-8 texts, too.

Comment: _"the string travels across a couple of functions in an std::string container up until it reaches the function I am creating"_ - Do any of those function take the string by non-`const` reference? If so, I suspect one of those is changing the string.

Comment: Hi, @TedLyngmo! Thanks for being here in the thread. Do you mean 'const std::string' form? Yes, I believe all the other functions just directly use 'std::string' as is. Should all of them use 'const' reference? Does that mean I would need to modify all of those functions? Thank you!

Comment: All the functions that are not _supposed_ to change the string should take it by `const&` (or by value, but `const&` is often better).

Comment: `std::string` is a just a string of bytes. It doesn't contain any information about encoding. The debugger can't know what encoding you intent the string to hold and it is probably making an assumption different from UTF-8. Have you checked whether the numeric byte values that the debugger is giving you are those that your string should have UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: But that's clearly not the string you are showing. You must have modified it somewhere on the way. I would guess that you are modifying the string somewhere, making wrong assumptions on how `std::string` would work with unicode. Please show a [mre], at least for the part that you transfer (and modify) the string in.

Comment: Hi, @user17732522! Thanks for being here in the thread! Yes, I did. Although I used wstring to know what numeric byte values should be correct if the encoding is UTF-8. The numeric byte values are different that is why my guess was that the string was encoded using other types of encoding.

Comment: Yes, @user17732522! That is right. I do think that the string has been modified along the way, as what I've mentioned in the question above. The UTF-8 encoded string is received from another device and it is received by a controller class (that I did not create) and it travels across a couple of functions before it will arrive to the function that I am creating. It arrives in my function in a different encoding already. And yes, I will try to create an MVCE so that I can attach it here. Thank you!

Comment: @DMPerez It is not (only) an encoding issue. The string shown in your debugger is clearly not the same string as the one in your question, regardless of encoding. It is for example Missing the whole `ASCII Extended` part at the beginning. Your code or the controller class must have cut if off somewhere. If we don't know how the string is being modified, it is pointless to speculate what the problem is. If the Controller code is modifying the string, you need to verify in its documentation that it also expects the string to be UTF-8 encoded, because `std::string` has no encoding information.

Comment: Hi. Please show a minimal reproducible example. You might also try showing us the 'function path' including the functions that lead to this result. But, your debug work could find the answer for you. Take a look at the string before it enters and leaves each of those intermediary functions. Also, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, @user17732522 Shaun Ramsey, and everyone! Thanks for supporting me through this thread! I very much appreciate it. Through your replies, I realized that I have not provided you all enough details on the issue. Please hang on while I create a minimal reproducible example so that you all will have enough idea of the problem. I will modify the question as soon as possible. Thank you all!

Comment: Hi @user17732522, sorry I took me a lot of time to get back to you all. I've edited my question above and tried to add the simplest code. I hope it's clearer now. Thank you all very much!

Comment: Hi @ShaunRamsey, sorry I took me a lot of time to get back to you all. I've edited my question above and tried to add the simplest code. I hope it's clearer now. Thank you all very much!

Comment: `std::copy` does not do any wide-string to UTF-8-string conversion. What you see is just that the high byte(s) of Unicode code points are truncated so that only the least significant 8 bits per character remain.

Comment: Hi, @j6t! Thanks for being here in the thread! Through all of your comments, now I understand what's happening here. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

> This is the existing code (take note: I did not create this code) that converted the std::wstring to std::string.

The function simply copies each code unit from the original string to the output string, implicitly converting the numeric value of the code unit according to the integer properties of `wchar_t` and `char`. Practically that means all code units are simply truncated to their lowest byte, loosing all other information. The function does not consider any encoding or anything. It is completely broken.

To convert from `std::wstring` to `std::string` you should first know how the input and output are intended to be encoded (e.g. the system's wide and narrow execution character set encoding) and then you should use a unicode library offering transcoding between these two encodings.

The C++ standard library does have functions for it (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert), but they are deprecated for security and specification problems and so shouldn't be used or used carefully.

If you want to convert from the native wide character set encoding to the current C locale's narrow multibyte encoding, you can also use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/wcsrtombs, but then you must also be careful to make sure that the correct locale is set.

A very complete unicode solution is ICU, but for what you are asking here you only need a tiny part of it.

On POSIX systems there is `iconv`.

You can find third party libraries as well.

Comment: Whoa thank you so much for this! I very much appreciate it. I think I understood the issue and will try out the recommended solution. Will get back here with the results. Thank you!

Comment: @DMPerez Please note that I don't recommend using either of the standard library functions I linked. I would recommend you to look for a third party library that doesn't share the problems of the standard library functions. The most complete unicode support is probably ICU, but for decoding/encoding you only need a tiny part of that. On POSIX systems there is iconv as part of the system.

Comment: Well noted. Thank you!